# Get Facebook Page posts using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Page where I am admin and I have a Facebook App where I am admin and have manage_pages permission - still, when using the Graph API Explorer with an App Token I get "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature...".

It has not been possible to get Page Public Content Access permission even though we have several pages with different admins (and we do not like to many admins on our App) and sometimes need to access posts from collaborators - and the Facebook docs seems very confusing and sometimes even contradictory when searching for a solution.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: _“Any ideas what I am missing here?”_ - the difference between app and page token …?

Comment: @04FS As far as I know the page token is in context of a user - the Page is public, I am only interested in public posts and, in the end, I need the data to be presented on a website where users will not be logged in. As I understand the docs this should be possible when a user is admin in both Page and App.

Comment: did you actually apply for page public content access?

Comment: @luschn Yes and got turned down 3 times, thats why we ended up with manage_pages as the respond was that it was enough.

Comment: You need to use a page token, only that proves that you actually have admin access to the page. An app token is generic, that does not contain any such information. If you use an app token, then your attempt to access the data would indeed be considered “public”, so you would need to apply for the Page Public Content Access feature.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the explanation. Do you have any experience in how to get the Page Public Content Access permission - we have produced a video and described that we need to show posts not in the context of a user but is still not getting approved (they say Manage_Pages or Read_Insights is enough) - maybe there is a buzzword or similar we can use the get the permission easier? Before September 4, 2019 using an App token was enough.

Comment: just authorize with manage_pages and generate a page token...you do NOT need page public content access if it is about pages you manage.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: @luschn So, if I manage the Pages the easiest is to generate a long-lived Page token (even yhough I don't like that it is still in a user context) and use that in my code - and if I am not admin of the Pages I need the Page Public Content Access permission?

Comment: exactly, it is that simple